# Xcode, Navigation View Controller

Tags: xcode, navigation, viewcontroller

I have a story board sequence as follows.

SplashView Controller > NavigationController > TableViewController

How do I code such that when I click on a button in SplashViewController, I will be directed to TableViewController WITH the NavigationBar. Because currently, when I code, I think I am linking directly to the TableView instead of the NavigationController, thus the navigation bar is not displayed. I know in story board, all I have to do it use "modal" and click and point to navigation controller. but how can I achieve it through coding.

Do you guys need any codes?

Comment: Try putting everything under the NavigationController, it should automatically give you the NavigationBar.

NavigationController > SplashViewController > TableViewController

Comment: Well, you could always use the delegate method and enable/disable a button based on whether or not the network data has been gathered and then if the button is enabled, it creates a segue to another ViewController.

Comment: @RJHill That's what I am doing, which is not what I need.. I need it to direct automatically WITHOUT a button. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I wanted to achieve was similar to a splash loading screen.
I have a delegate method which receives signal from another class when it has competed gathering data form the network.
Anyone who is interested in doing a splash this way, below is the answer.

```
-(void) receivedData{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *secondView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
[self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

Anyway the above methods has a potential of giving me a transition error as the view might proceed to the next view without waiting for the current view to be completed, causing a potential crash. Just add the method

```
 -viewDidAppear()
```

and run your codes inside viewDidAppear